# delphi :how get & pass image to dropzone programilty

Tags: javascript, delphi-xe2

i tryed to build ROBOT APP for The issuance of visas to Saudi Arabia.the app able login to web site with the user account and fill (name,age,sex....) it's done with my app but the last step is upload picture 
there is dropzone fot drag image from local disk and drop it to dropzone for upload with following HTML CODE

```
      <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
    <div class="dz-details">
    <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
    <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
  <img data-dz-thumbnail />
  </div>
  <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-    uploadprogress></span></div>
```

HOW TO CAN PASS IMAGE TO DROPZONE PROGRAMLITY WITHOUT MOUSE EVENT OR HTTP UPLOAD BECOSE I DON'T HAVE API(i mean database password). 
i have Tform with Tedit(full picture path) and Twebbrowser and button when the user click button after my app fill evry data then do something like pass picture to dropzone for upload as final step.
sorry for my language i use google Translation
please i need help with some code example 
thanks

Comment: note:i don't know how i can use The-Drag-and-Drop-Component-Suite or Dropmaster i have both but nothing done

Comment: if there are javascript sample & easy function do what i wont i will execute with delphi becose am not professional javascript